# RadGrid - Get object from specific cell from clientside

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm trying to set up a toggle so that a user can use a list of objects as a To Do list. I'm looking for a way that a user can click a row, and it will toggle a span from one font-icon to another. I'm also looking to not hit the server at all.

Currently I have this javascript function, which is called by the ClientEvents `OnRowClick` event in the ClientSettings portion of my radgrid.

```
    function ToggleMark(sender, eventArgs) {
        var spn = eventArgs.get_item().findElement("spnMarker");
        if(spn.className == "icon-minus") { spn.className = "icon-checkmark"; }
        else { spn.className = "icon-minus"; }
    }
```

It is attached to a grid with this template. The span `spnMarker` is the element that I'm interested in.

```
    <rad:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ManualMarker" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Width="12px" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <span id="spnMarker" class="icon-minus" style="font-size:20px;display:inline;"></span>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </rad:GridTemplateColumn>
```

This will select and toggle the first element of my grid, but not the element that I click on specifically. I was originally messing around with `get_itemIndexHierarchical()` to select it from a listing of all of the items, but I must have been doing that wrong, since I got the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I didn't notice you could set things as code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how you can get a cell by a concrete column: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-getting-cell-values-for-selected-rows-client-side.html

Comment: This gets the cell in question, but I'm interested in getting the object in that cell. Once I have the cell, how do I get the relevant ID of the span tag inside?

Comment: jQuery? If it is a control, you know its server ID, so you can use and endsWith selector. Or use CSS classes

Comment: Thanks! Sorry this took me a long time to respond to. The endsWith selector worked, but I also found an easier way around the problem I was trying to solve. Much appreciated!